# Serialization Issue on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios5, soap, dictionary, ios6

In my project i have implemented multiple service and getting response. Among that one WSDL service that returns one data set as a response,

```
+ (id)deserializeAsDictionary:(CXMLNode*)element {
    NSLog(@"deserializeAsDictionary = %@, children: %d", element.stringValue, [element childCount]);

    if([element childCount] == 1) {
        CXMLNode* child = [[element children] objectAtIndex:0];
        if([child kind] == CXMLTextKind) {
            NSLog(@"child %@ added", [child stringValue]);
            return [[[element children] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
        }
    }

    NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSInteger i = 1;
    NSString *objKey;
    for(CXMLNode* child in [element children]) {
        id v = [Soap deserialize:child];
        if(v == nil) { 
            v = [NSNull null]; 
        } else {
            if([[child name] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]) {
                objKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[child stringValue]];
            } else if([[child name] isEqualToString:@"key"] || [[child name] isEqualToString:@"value"]) { 
                objKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[child name]];
            } else {
                objKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",[child name],i++];
            }

        }

        [d setObject:v forKey:objKey];
        NSLog(@"child %@ added", objKey);
    }
    return d;
}
```

soap class will use this method to convert that data set into dictionary. Its working perfectly in IOS 5 but its not working in ios 6. Application will crash in ios 6 and through error as " **CXML copy with zone** "Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u get the soap classes with ARC enabled for ios6.If so you need to update the soap request class.Please refer this link [Sudzc with iOS 5 and ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645637/sudzc-with-ios-5-and-arc)
I think it may useful to you